# Change a value in a python 2d array

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a 2D list and want to change one of the values inside of it

I have tried converting to a list and back again.
But i do not think that is what I am looking for.

```py
a = [(3, 12, .05), (6, 1, .3)]
a[0][2] = 543
```

Comment: Why not use a list of lists?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once a **[tuple](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_tuples.asp)** is created, you cannot change its values. Tuples are **unchangeable**, or **immutable** as it also is called.

But there is a workaround. You can convert the tuple into a list, change the list, and convert the list back into a tuple.

```
a = [(3, 12, .05), (6, 1, .3)]
y = list(a[0])
y[2] = 543
a[0] = tuple(y)
print a
```

Comment: Thanks I know similar questions had been asked but your answer was exactly what I needed I was trying to turn the whole thing into a list like y = a[0][1]. Thanks Heaps

Comment: I'm happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

As @ShantesharInde said, tuples are unchangeable/immutable. They are declared by parentheses (). Lists are created by brackets []. So in your code a is a list of tuples. Two ways to make it changeable/mutable.

Method 1: Change declaration

```
>>> a = [[3, 12, .05], [6, 1, .3]]
>>> a[0][2] = 543
>>> a
[[3, 12, 543], [6, 1, 0.3]]
```

Method 2: convert inner tuples to lists

```
>>> a = [(3, 12, .05), (6, 1, .3)]
>>> for idx, item in enumerate(a):
...     a[idx] = list(item)
... 
>>> a[0][2] = 543 
>>> a
[[3, 12, 543], [6, 1, 0.3]]
```

The for loop with enumerate is a nice way of doing things if your list has many entries. For just two elements, you could just do

```
a[0] = list(a[0])
a[1] = list(a[1])
```

If you're wondering why converting to list didn't work for you before, it's because the list() function will only try to convert the outermost elements. So converting a list to a list has no effect.